# Websocket response data undefined in global variable

Tags: javascript, websocket, global-variables, undefined

I would like to use the global variable data and assign the WebSocket response data to it but
inside the function the data is displayed outside is undefined.

How can I solve this?

```
var data;

client.onopen = () => {
  console.log("WebSocket Client Connected!");
};

client.onmessage = (message) => {
  data = message.data;
  console.log(data); // json data in console
};

client.onerror = function () {
  console.log("Connection Error");
};

console.log(data); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the last console.log happens before the socket event happens that why the variable is undefined if you want to see the variable you need to call it by function after the socket event emited

Comment: How do I wait until the socket event is finished?

Comment: Put the console log in function and call this function when the event emited

Comment: Could you show me how because I cannot seem to work it out. I want to use data the like this later on.          ...  var best = data.BEST.slice(0, 3);

Comment: Can you give me  example of when you will use this variable  and i will told you how to use it

Comment: This variable is used in a function like this getBest(best)[0][1] and getBest(best)[1][1], so basically the data i get from the websocket is JSON and I slice it first then use it

Comment: Ok so just use the variable in this function and it will work perfectly but make sure you don't call this function before the socket run at least one

Comment: How do I run it at least once? I am using it in the same file immediately. But the problem is still that when I want to use the data variable it is still undefined.

Comment: Just emit this socket from client you can  read this documentation https://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

The data variable is not defined at the time when `console.log` executes, you tried to log the variable to the console **before** your client received the message.